# scheduleAtFixedRate-timer does not work (Android in Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, timer, illegalargumentexception

I am using a scheduleAtFixedRate-timer for my Android app in Eclipse, but it does not work:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, (long) 0, (long) interval*1000);
```

where interval can for example be 0.5. However, this works:

```
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, (long) 0, (long) 500);
```

And a schedule-timer also works:

```
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(task, (long) interval*1000);
```

I think this is strange and don't know why the emulator gives an illegalargumentexception. Can someone help me out?

Edit: stack trace

```
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855): Process: com.example.bulerias, PID: 855
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Timer.java:526)
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at com.example.bulerias.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:92)
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-20 12:29:54.080: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace

Comment: Just a minute (the compiler is very slow)

Comment: I have posted the stack trace

Comment: instead of 0 specify a delay

Comment: I assume `(long) interval` would cast `interval` to long, `(long) 0.5 == 0`, hence your period is 0. you need to `(long) (interval * 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29), an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown if `delay < 0` or `period <= 0` in `scheduleAtFixedRate`. Therefore, I assume: `period == 0`.
You should check your period to ensure it is not 0:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
long period = (long) interval*1000;
Log.i("sometag", "period = " period);
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, (long) 0, period);
```